# Conditional formatting of datagrid columns in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following style defined in my code for a datagrid text column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGrid_CellStyle_Right}">
       <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=OrderByColumn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="2">
               <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource LargeFontSize}"/>
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
          </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

A similar style is set for each column with only the value of the DataTrigger changing (2 for the second column, 3 for the 3rd, 4 for the 4th and so forth).

The idea is that I set the OrderByColumn property in the XAML when I use the control so that I can selectively format a given column (the property itself exists in the code behind of the UserControl). The font size is being respected for the column (the resource LargeFontSize is both found and used) but not the background colour which seems to stay the same no matter what I do. The style that is all based on has no colour to override at this point.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your UserControl really has a property OrderByColumn? Or its DataContext?

Comment: The user control.

Comment: Is OrderByColumn a dependency property?

Comment: Does trigger work at all, tried to set more properties to hardcoded values? Tried to reproduce the case from scratch?

Comment: OrderByColumn is a dependency property yes. It's clearly being found too as the font size is being set in the column, just not the background colour.

Comment: This code and your explanations are not enough to figure out the reason.
I repeated your implementation and it works for me without any problems.
Make a mini, runnable example that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the ControlTemplate which I had completely forgotten about was preventing the other styles from being presented as expected. Removing this allowed the column colour to be shown. It added other formatting issues in the process but these at least could be fixed.

In any case thank you for the comments and help but it seems this problem has been fixed.